# Constant storage size in the rolling history mode?

Tags: storage, snapshots

Under the "rolling" history mode, does the size of a node's stored data remains roughly constant in time? If yes, what is the size currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a node, the `store` is responsible of storing blocks (headers, operations, …) and the `context` stores the ledger state (balances, contracts, …).

In the current rolling mode implementation, only the store is cleaned on regular basis (at the beginning of a new cycle). Indeed, the garbage collection (deletion of unreachable elements) of the context is not currently efficient enough to be implemented in the node release. A new storage back-end is currently developed and tested to allow a more reliable context cleaning.

In terms of storage consumption, the store size should increase during a cycle and remain roughly constant between each cycles starts (when triggering the cleanup). The same behavior (modulo new accounts, contracts, …) is expected on the context with the future back-end.

It is quite difficult to give precise figures as it vary regarding the network load and the protocol.